# Google cloud storage uploading file with different file name

Tags: bash, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I can upload any file with original file name via bash script. But when i change file name with gsutil cp command system giving file not found error.

For example my script is;

```
#!/bin/sh -x
#PATH=/root/gsutil
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
export BOTO_CONFIG="/root/.boto"
NOW=$(/bin/date +"%d-%m-%Y")
LASTDB=$(/bin/find /media/bckdrv/backup/ -type f -name "db*" -printf '%p\n'| sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2 -d" ")
/root/gsutil/gsutil cp $LASTDB gs://radb/webdb/daily/db_$NOW.GZ
```

I can run this on terminal without any error. But when run with cron i take Not found error.

Log is below;

```
+ PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
+ export BOTO_CONFIG=/root/.boto
+ BOTO_CONFIG=/root/.boto
++ /bin/date +%d-%m-%Y
+ NOW=07-08-2014
++ /bin/find /media/bckdrv/backup/ -type f -name 'db*' -printf '%p\n'
++ sort -n
++ tail -1
++ cut -f2 '-d '
+ LASTDB=/media/bckdrv/backup/db-9755.GZ
+ /root/gsutil/gsutil cp /media/bckdrv/backup/db-9755.GZ gs://radb/webdb/daily/db_07-08-2014.GZ
+ PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin
+ export BOTO_CONFIG=/root/.boto
+ BOTO_CONFIG=/root/.boto
++ /bin/date +%d-%m-%Y
+ NOW=07-08-2014
++ /bin/find /media/bckdrv/backup/ -type f -name 'db*' -printf '%p\n'
++ sort -n
++ tail -1
++ cut -f2 '-d '
+ LASTDB=/media/bckdrv/backup/db-9755.GZ
+ /root/gsutil/gsutil cp /media/bckdrv/backup/db-9755.GZ gs://radb/webdb/daily/db_07-08-2014.GZ
Copying file:///media/bckdrv/backup/db-9755.GZ [Content-Type=application/x-gzip]...
Failure: list index out of range.
Copying file:///media/bckdrv/backup/db-9755.GZ [Content-Type=application/x-gzip]...
Failure: list index out of range.
```

IF i change script last line from

```
/root/gsutil/gsutil cp $LASTDB gs://radb/webdb/daily/db_$NOW.GZ
```

to

```
/root/gsutil/gsutil cp $LASTDB gs://radb/webdb/daily/
```

Scripts can upload successfully with original file name.

So how can i fix that problem ? I don't want to change original file name which on my local .

Comment: As a workaround, try copying your file locally, rename the copy and upload it, and after delete it locally.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the purpose is to copy a single file to GCS. Can't the script be simplified any further? I made a similar test where I copy a log file directly to the cloud storage bucket while changing its name by adding the time. I had no issues in the process and cron was able to run it every minute (for testing). I do everything with a single command in my example, I understand that you might need to add some sorting as with your DB variable or find a different way to specify the file in question.

Here's the sample:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Description: Copy specified log file to GCS
NOW=$(/bin/date +"%d-%m-%Y")

/usr/local/bin/gsutil cp /var/log/logfilename gs://bucketname/filename$NOW
```

Comment: Hi, this is making same work like my script. My LASTDB variable only finding last backup file name.

Comment: If you run the two scripts, do they both generate the same error?